# Prevent JButton repaint() after click

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, setbackground

I have a button. I want to change the background after I click on it. My problem here is the button auto call `paintComponent()`. How can prevent this? I expect after clicking the button the button will be blue, but it will still be red.

```
package test;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class ButtonDemo extends JButton implements ActionListener{

    public ButtonDemo() {
        this.setText("BUTTON TEXT");
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        setBackground(Color.RED);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.add(new ButtonDemo());
        frame.setSize(500, 500);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    }  
}
```

Comment: So, essentially, you want to have a "toggle" button of some kind - Maybe start by having a look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), I'd pay close attention to the `JToggleButton`.  If this isn't doing exactly what you want, then you might need to investigating building your own `ButtonModel`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm using button for a chess man. I call ```setBackground``` in ```paintComponent```. When i click on a chess man, i want change background color to red(like hint) and after that, i call repaint() to get default color. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: Please see: [Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22232) for Stack Overflow's / Stack Exchange's policy wrt. keeping wording professional.

Comment: @Puskin I'm thinking that `JButton` only probably isn't the right choice, but I'd be looking for a solution where I could set the `border` property instead

Comment: @Puskin *" I call setBackground in paintComponent"* - Ah, no - don't modify the state of the component from within the `paintComponent`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I put ```Jbutton``` inside a ```Jpanel``` like squares of a chessboard. I tried setting ```setBackground()``` of each Jbutton inside Jpanel's ```paintComponent()``` but after calling ```repaint()``` the buttons would not be visible until hovered over. Do you know how to solve this problem? I am thinking of something that can replace the button

Comment: Do not call any methods from paintComponent which change the button’s state!  paintComponent is for painting *only.*  In fact, changing the background will likely cause *another repaint.*  If you’re going to change the background, do it in an event listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal gut feeling is that `JButton` is probably not suited to your desired goal.

Essentially, you want to control when and how the "selected" state of the piece is changed.

Personally, I would have some kind of controller which monitored the mouse events in some way (probably having the piece component delegate the event back to the controller) and some kind of model which control when pieces become selected, this would then notify the controller of the state change and it would make appropriate updates to the UI.

But that's a long process to setup.  Instead, I'm demonstrating a simple concept where a component can be selected with the mouse, but only the controller can de-select.   In this example, this will allow only a single piece to be selected

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));

            ChangeListener listener = new ChangeListener() {
                private PiecePane selectedPiece;

                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    if (!(e.getSource() instanceof PiecePane)) { return; }

                    PiecePane piece = (PiecePane) e.getSource();

                    // Want to ignore events from the selected piece, as this
                    // might interfer with the changing of the pieces
                    if (selectedPiece == piece) { return; }

                    if (selectedPiece != null) {
                        selectedPiece.setSelecetd(false);
                        selectedPiece = null;
                    }

                    selectedPiece = piece;
                }
            };

            for (int index = 0; index < 5 * 5; index++) {
                PiecePane pane = new PiecePane();
                pane.addChangeListener(listener);
                add(pane);
            }
        }

    }

    public class PiecePane extends JPanel {

        private boolean selecetd;
        private Color selectedBackground;
        private Color normalBackground;

        private MouseListener mouseListener;

        public PiecePane() {
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));
            mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                    setSelecetd(true);
                }
            };

            setNormalBackground(Color.BLUE);
            setSelectedBackground(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(50, 50);
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify(); 
            addMouseListener(mouseListener);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify(); 
            removeMouseListener(mouseListener);
        }

        public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
            listenerList.add(ChangeListener.class, listener);
        }

        public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
            listenerList.remove(ChangeListener.class, listener);
        }

        protected void fireSelectionChanged() {
            ChangeListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ChangeListener.class);
            if (listeners.length == 0) {
                return;
            }
            ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
            for (int index = listeners.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
                listeners[index].stateChanged(evt);
            }
        }

        public boolean isSelected() {
            return selecetd;
        }

        public void setSelecetd(boolean selecetd) {
            if (selecetd == this.selecetd) { return; }
            this.selecetd = selecetd;
            updateSelectedState();
            fireSelectionChanged();
        }

        public Color getSelectedBackground() {
            return selectedBackground;
        }

        public void setSelectedBackground(Color selectedBackground) {
            this.selectedBackground = selectedBackground;
            updateSelectedState();
        }

        public Color getNormalBackground() {
            return normalBackground;
        }

        public void setNormalBackground(Color normalBackground) {
            this.normalBackground = normalBackground;
            updateSelectedState();
        }

        protected void updateSelectedState() {
            if (isSelected()) {
                setBackground(getSelectedBackground());
            } else {
                setBackground(getNormalBackground());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo: `public void setSelecetd(boolean selecetd)`

Comment: Thank you, I still use the button, I solved this problem by not calling``` repaint()``` anymore but calling a self-writing method with the same content. This will avoid Swing's painting layer problem (problem which don't fully understand).

Answer (score 1):

I created a toggle button.

You set the primary color and the alternate color in the class constructor.

When you call the `switchColors` method, the `JButton` background changes from the primary color to the alternate color.  When you call the `switchColors` method again, the `JButton` background changes from the alternate color to the primary color.

In the following example, I put the `switchColors` method in the actionListener so you can see the color change.  Each time you left-click on the JButton, the background color changes.

You would call the `switchColors` method when you want the `JButton` background to change from blue to red, and again when you want the `JButton` background to change from red to blue.  It's under your control.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class ButtonDemo extends JButton 
        implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Button Demo");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(
                        JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
                contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
                contentPane.add(new ButtonDemo(Color.BLUE, 
                        Color.RED));
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private boolean primaryBackground;

    private Color primaryColor;
    private Color alternateColor;

    public ButtonDemo(Color primaryColor, 
            Color alternateColor) {
        this.primaryColor = primaryColor;
        this.alternateColor = alternateColor;
        this.primaryBackground = true;

        this.setText("BUTTON TEXT");
        this.setBackground(primaryColor);
        this.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void switchColors() {
        primaryBackground = !primaryBackground;
        Color color = primaryBackground ? primaryColor :
            alternateColor;
        this.setBackground(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switchColors();
    }

}
```

Comment: I must to override ```paintComponent()``` for my button. I just want my Button change color when I click and after that, I call repaint() and get red color

Comment: @Puskin: You didn't mention that in your question.  Quote, " I want to change background after click on it."  That's what my answer code does.

Comment: I'm using button for a chess man. I call ```setBackground``` in ```paintComponent``` When i click on a chess man, i want change background color to red(like hint) and after that, i call repaint() to get default color. Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: @Puskin: What I don't understand in your comment is "after that".  Edit your question to describe exactly the sequence of events that turn your button red, and then blue.  Possibly, the sequence would happen so fast no one would see it.

Comment: Exactly. And i want to prevent repaint() after i click. So my button can hold red color until i call repaint()

Comment: @Puskin: You don't have that kind of control over Swing repainting.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background for a short while you can do it with swing `Timer`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ButtonDemo extends JButton implements ActionListener{

    private static final int DELAY = 600; //milliseconds
    private final Timer timer;

    public ButtonDemo() {
        this.setText("BUTTON TEXT");
        this.addActionListener(this);
        Color defaultCloor = getBackground();
        timer = new Timer(DELAY, e-> setBackground(defaultCloor));
        timer.setRepeats(false);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.add(new ButtonDemo());
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.stop();
        this.setBackground(Color.RED);
        timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I want it not to be a specific time, but to be under my control, when I do something else it will return to its original color.