# How to make a sequential color change on multiple buttons with an Action Listener in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I want to make a very simple GUI app.

What I'm trying to do is to change the background colors of three buttons as I press a fourth one. The kind of color change that I want is sequential:
When I press the fourth button, the first one immediately changes its color, then a period of four seconds will happen and the second button changes as well, after that, another time period will occur and finally the last button (third one) changes.

The big deal is that I can achieve this if I put the color-change code into the class constructor, but I can't if I put the code into the button Action Listener definition. If I try the last way, the color change is performed differently: time periods go first and then suddenly the three buttons change their colors. I don't want this since it's not sequential.

I need that it works as expected (sequentially) when the fourth button is pressed.

Here's my not-working code:

```
public class exalumno extends JFrame {
    private JButton b1;
    private JButton b2;
    private JButton b3;
    private JButton b4;

    public exalumno() {
        setTitle("test");
        setSize(400, 100);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        b1 = new JButton("a");
        b2 = new JButton("b");
        b3 = new JButton("c");
        b4 = new JButton("changeColors");
        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(b3);
        add(b4);
        ActionListener jk = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                try {
                    b1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                    b2.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                    b3.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        b4.addActionListener(jk);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main (String[]args){
        new exalumno();
    }
}
```

As you can see I implement time periods with `Thread.sleep()`.

I'd appreciate your help a lot.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use Thread.sleep(). That will block the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) which will prevent the GUI from repainting itself until all the code is executed. Instead you need to use a `Swing Timer` to schedule the animation. When the Timer fires the first time you change button1, the second time button2 and the third timer button 3, then you stop the Timer. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more information.

Comment: See an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61435744/3992939) of using a Sing Timer to change the background color of a button.