# How to use JLabel and Swing Timer to briefly notify the user?

Tags: java, swing, timer, jlabel

I'm working on a small app for a class. One of the functions I want is when a button is clicked, it adds an object to an `ArrayList` based on the fields that they filled. When they click they button, I want them to have visual confirmation that the action has been performed. However, just updating a `JLabel` would cause it to sit there forever after the button was clicked.

- I would like the label to start off displaying "".
- When the button is clicked, I want it to say "Character Added!"
- ..for a few seconds. and then switch back to "".

I looked up some questions about label updating using a timer, but most of them have been using it to display a counting down clock, and they usually use a timer start method. I'm confused about if you need a timer stop method to reset the label.

Any pointers?

Comment: See [`Timer.setRepeats(false)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/Timer.html#setRepeats(boolean))

Comment: See an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61435744/3992939) of using swing timer for a short-lasted change of a `JLable`. The example changes the color, but can be easily modified to change text.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is, instead of using a `JLabel` that updates, I simply made it so when the button is pressed and a character is added to the `ArrayList`, I called

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialogue("Character Added!");`

That way instead of a small little `JLabel` confirming it, they get a very apparent notification that requires them to acknowledge it. Tons more simple than doing the whole `Timer` thing.